# mp4 to gif converter failing to produce

Tags: python, gif, mp4, converters, python-imageio

I'm struggling with my converter from mp4 to gif.

Its basically been put together from imageio website and YouTube, but cant get it to work.

```
#[python converter.py]
import imageio
import os

clip = os.path.abspath('six.mp4')

def gifMaker(inputPath,targetFormat):
    outputPath = os.path.splitext(inputPath)[0] + (targetFormat)
    
    print(f'converting {inputPath} \n to {outputPath}')
     
    reader = imageio.get_reader(inputPath)
    fps = reader.get_meta_data()['fps']
    
    writer = imageio.get_reader(outputPath, fps=fps)
    
    for frames in reader:
        writer.append_data(frames)
        print (f'frame {frames}')
    print('Klart')
    writer.close()

gifMaker (clip, '.gif')
```

Comment: typo on `writer` variable?

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you are creating "writer":

```
writer = imageio.get_reader(outputPath, fps=fps)
```

Just change the *get_reader* call for *get_writer*

```
writer = imageio.get_writer(outputPath, fps=fps)
```

That should be enough to make it work.